# Remove focus from textbox when clicking on parent grid in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a simple window that has a few buttons and a textbox. I want that when I press "Enter" on my keyboard this will trigger a button command but the problem is that when I'm focused on the textbox, I can't press "Enter" because it will just add a linebreak to the textbox.

I tried binding a LeftClick gesture of the grid to a command that uses keyboard.ClearFocus() but I guess that isn't the right function because that didn't work.
Another option which might work but I didn't try yet and I'm not sure if it's even a good practice, is adding x:Name to the textbox, and sending the window as the parameter to the command.

I want that when I click the parent grid of the textbox the focused will be removed from it so I can press "Enter", is there a simple way to do it in MVVM?

Answer (score 0):

You said: "I want that when I press Enter on my keyboard this will trigger a button command"

Have you tried adding InputBindings to the text box?

```
<TextBox.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Return" Command="{Binding YourCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}}}"/>
</TextBox.InputBindings>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, The problem is I do want the textbox to accept return.

Comment: @Nadavs2310 hmm, I might be misunderstanding what you're looking for. But anyway, to get the click on the parent grid to take keyboard focus, maybe try adding

    PreviewMouseDown="Grid_MouseDown"

to the parent grid, then in the codebehind, in the Grid_MouseDown method, setting the KeyboardFocus to the parent grid. I bet you could do this with style triggers too instead.

Comment: I have an application that generally randomizes questions, there is a textbox in which the user inputs his answer and there is a button to show his answer next to the correct answer.
Now I want that it will be possible to trigger the check answer command also by clicking Enter (I could use another key, but Enter is natural for most people), the problem is I need the textbox to accept return.
The solution with the event is possible but I want to avoid code behind due to the MVVM pattern.

Comment: I believe the code snippet in my answer will allow your textbox to accept return. You can bind to your check answer command (presumably in a viewmodel) where it says "{Binding YourCommand}"

Comment: So what do you want to do when the `TextBox` is focused and you press `ENTER`? Add a new line or execute a command? Or both?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, when focused on the textbox I want it to add a new line, but when not I want it to trigger a command. The problem is the form doesn't have anywhere to click to remove focus from the textbox, so always when pressing enter, it will add a new line to the textbox. @mm8

Comment: @Nadavs2310: I don't understand. Where is the focus when you click and want to trigger the command?